# How do i multiply the indices of complex matrices to get a new complex matrix

Tags: python, numpy, matrix-multiplication, complex-numbers

```py
import numpy as np

Matrix1 = [[1.45 + 7.12j], [-7.42 + 7.42j]]
Matrix2 = [1, 0]
Product = []

for i, x in zip(Matrix1, Matrix2):
    Product.append(i * x)

print(Product)
```

i get the `TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-in of type 'list'.`

Comment: Why did you import `numpy`? Do you know how matrix-vector multiplication works? Do you know what that `TypeError` means?

Answer (score 1):

```
In [5]: Matrix1=[[1.45+7.12j] , [-7.42+7.42j]]
   ...: Matrix2=[1,0]
In [6]: Matrix1
Out[6]: [[(1.45+7.12j)], [(-7.42+7.42j)]]
In [7]: Matrix2
Out[7]: [1, 0]
In [8]: Matrix1[0]*Matrix2[0]
Out[8]: [(1.45+7.12j)]
In [9]: Product=[]
   ...: for i,x in zip(Matrix1,Matrix2):
   ...:   Product.append(i*x)
In [10]: Product
Out[10]: [[(1.45+7.12j)], []]
```

`Matrix1` is a list of lists; each sublist contains one complex number.  List * integer is not numeric multiplication; it is a repetition.   That's why `Product` contains one list of length one, and another of length 0.

This isn't right, but it isn't your error either!

The integer *:

```
In [11]: Matrix1[0]*1
Out[11]: [(1.45+7.12j)]
In [12]: Matrix1[0]*0
Out[12]: []
```

but assume `Matrix2` has nested lists:

```
In [13]: Matrix1[0]*[1]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-13-c26e0c05c20a>", line 1, in <module>
    Matrix1[0]*[1]
TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'list'
```

That's your error.  You can't multiply 2 lists.

But replace the lists with arrays:

```
In [17]: A=np.array(Matrix1)
In [18]: B=np.array(Matrix2)
In [19]: A,B
Out[19]: 
(array([[ 1.45+7.12j],
        [-7.42+7.42j]]),
 array([1, 0]))
In [21]: [i*x for i,x in zip(A,B)]
Out[21]: [array([1.45+7.12j]), array([-0.+0.j])]
```

Now we can do numeric multiplication.